# Get GMT time in milli sec in python

Tags: java, python, python-3.x

Trying to get GMT in milli secs in Python, I could achieve it in Java but need help with python.
Java version:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
long time = cal.getTimeInMillis();
Sample output - 1528893731677
```

Python version:

```
millis = int(round(time.time() * 1000)) // How to get GMT time here?
Sample output - 1528953926983
```

Comment: Take a look at time.gmtime().

Comment: Actually, that Java code is obsolete. Modern approach: [`Instant.now().toEpochMilli()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.utcnow().timestamp() * 1000)
```

Comment: Works fine with print(int(datetime.utcnow().timestamp() * 1000))

Answer (score 0):

Credits to @David

```
import time
gmt  = time.gmtime()
millis = gmt.tm_hour*3600000 + gmt.tm_min*60000 + gmt.tm_sec*1000
print(millis)
```